# Add Form Data and Get Data from Another Table to Form a New Record After Submit - Php MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, forms

5 fields from Table 1 come from the Php Form.  5 fields are extracted from Table 2, Table 3, Table 4, and Table 5.

Is this doable from Php?

Tried both multiple INSERT SELECT and VIEWS; however, a novice compared to some.

```
<?php
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$link = mysqli_connect("site", "user", "password", "database");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$new_record_id = trim($_GET["id"]); 

// Attempt insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO persons (first_name, last_name, email, city, state) VALUES ('Peter', 'Parker', 'peterparker@mail.com', 'williamsburg', 'new york')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Records inserted successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// Attempt insert query1 execution
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO persons (SELECT cust_type, cust_revenues, cust_since FROM customer) VALUES ('Existing', '3029', '2016') WHERE id = $new_record_id";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Records inserted successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// Attempt insert query2 execution
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO persons (SELECT order_no, order_date FROM orders) VALUES ('293048', '11/26/2016') WHERE id = $new_record_id";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Records inserted successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

When submitting the Form, a new record should get created with data in all 10 fields. Currently, not happening.

Comment: NOTE:  Combined Tables 4 and 5 with Tables 2 and 3.

Comment: What are the error messages? What do you get when you run the select statements alone?

Comment: I don't see in your code where `$new_record_id` is set.

Answer (score 0):

I think I will replace the code with PDO hardened PHP statements and MySQLi. As well since no error codes are given (it returns a clean page), I think the result set is too big. I replaced the query to only perform an `INSERT` from the `Form`. The other tables will be aggregated into Views.